# why thread id of previously killed boost thread is assigned to the new boost thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

Facing a issue with boost thread Thread id
The scenario is as follows
Boost Thread A is generated with threadid assume 1234 
Boost Thread B is generated with threadid assume 7890
Boost Thread C is generated, by this time thread A has completed his run function and ended so thread id assigned to Thread C by boost is 1234

From os perspective thread id should be unique
why does boost assigns the  previously killed boost thread id to the new thread?

I have to debug some issue for which I need a unique identification of a thread
(the reuse to thread id causes confusions)

is their a way to assign thread id to the boost thread explicitly
or any other unique identification for the boost thread

Comment: When something says it's "unique" you have to define exactly what that means.  In this case; a unique thread id is one that is not currently used; it does not mean unique in OS run time; or unique in lifetime of computer; or unique absolute.  From this definition of unique; once you join with the thread; there's no reason why the id can't be re-used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost makes no guarantees that thread ids will not be reused.  Per [the Boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html):

> **Thread IDs**
>
> Objects of class `boost::thread::id` can be used to identify threads.
>   **Each running thread of execution has a unique ID** obtainable from the
>   corresponding `boost::thread` by calling the `get_id()` member
>   function, or by calling `boost::this_thread::get_id()` from within the
>   thread. Objects of class `boost::thread::id` can be copied, and used
>   as keys in associative containers: the full range of comparison
>   operators is provided. Thread IDs can also be written to an output
>   stream using the stream insertion operator, though the output format
>   is unspecified.
>
> Each instance of `boost::thread::id` either refers to some thread, or
>   `Not-a-Thread`. Instances that refer to `Not-a-Thread` compare equal
>   to each other, but not equal to any instances that refer to an actual
>   thread of execution. The comparison operators on `boost::thread::id`
>   yield a total order for every non-equal thread ID.

Note that thread ids are guaranteed to be unique only between *running* threads.

You need to create your own id for your thread objects, and make sure it can not be reused for the lifetime of your process.  A simple synchronized 64-bit one-up counter should be more than sufficient.  Even if you create 1000 threads per second, it'd probably take 100 billion years or so to wrap back to zero.  Your process isn't likely to run for that long.

Comment: In fairness, thread ids **are** guaranteed to not be reused if the thread has not been detached. In that respect it's a bit like zombie processes.

Comment: For fun: `qalc "2^64 / 1000Hz to years"` displays `(2^64) / (1000 * hertz) = approx. 584.54205 megayears`